# How to remove .Trash folder from iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, big-sur

There's an invisible folder in my iCloud folder -> `.Trash`

iCloud seems to sync the mac's trash folder to the cloud. How do I remove/exclude it from there? If I try to delete it conventionally I get `error code -50`.

Answer (score 6):

Golden Rule: Don't play with .Trash folders. Leave them alone.

The way macOS handles the myriad Trash folders right across your computer is not to be played with. Every user has one, every drive has one, local or remote mounted, every iCloud sync account has one, the system itself has one.
Don't touch. Consider them 'voodoo'.

You can easily see them if you Show Invisibles  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>.</kbd> 
Here are a few, including the one in iCloud Drive.
Note they don't all even have the same name - `.Trash` vs `Trash` vs `.Trashes` - another part of the 'voodoo'.

[image]

Comment: I suspect that what you're saying is true, but can you offer some evidence or documentation to back up your claim?

Comment: @EJMak - Just show invisibles & go hunting. They're not hard to spot. See how many you can find. Picture added to answer.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to show the `.Trash` folders, but I'm asking if you can offer evidence or back up your claim that these folders should "never be touched," are "voodoo," because it's a "golden rule," etc. Does Apple say so in their documentation? Are there specific/real examples of bad things that have happened, or will happen, if this advice is not followed? Again, you are probably right that tinkering with these folders is not a good idea if you don't know what you're doing, but you're making a strong blanket statement without offering a foundation.

Comment: @EJMak - Apple rarely says anything about things you shouldn't do - usually because the OS will stop you doing them & if you try to circumvent things, they shrug their shoulders & ask when your last backup was. You don't *need* documentation to tell you that messing with the depths of the OS is going to cause trouble. Try it for yourself - see if you can delete one.

Answer (score 4):

The `.Trash` in your iCloud Drive only stores the trash of your iCloud Drive, meaning if you delete a file/folder in iCloud, it will be moved to `.Trash`, and finally be deleted once you empty the trash on any device that syncs with iCloud Drive.

Files you delete on your Mac that are not in iCloud Drive will not be moved (and therefor uploaded) to your iCloud Drives `.Trash` folder (instead they land in the appropriate `.Trash` such as the one in your user folder (`~/.Trash`)).